# Привязка выпадающего списка к правой стороне родительского элемента

Tags: jquery, css

Есть [список](http://codepen.io/scottb/pen/gixIv) и скрипт, который список показывает и скрывает. Но список привязан к левому краю блока со ссылкой, а как можно сделать, чтобы привязка была к правому краю независимо от ширины блока ссылки?

```
<nav>
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu</a>
<ul class="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>

$(function() {

// Dropdown toggle
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
});

$(document).click(function(e) {
  var target = e.target;
  if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
    $('.dropdown').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте:

```
nav {
    float: right;
}
ul.dropdown {
    right: 0;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waMeQN)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вариант рабочий. Сейчас думаю, как сделать, чтобы список выпадал вверх, нужно для нижнего меню. Вариант .css('margin-top', (dropdown.innerHeight())) как-то некорректно работает

Comment: @Torawhite, если я правильно понял, как-то так [update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVGOPG)

Comment: спасибо! Да, именно так. А ларчик просто открывался(с) Всего лишь bottom:100%:

Answer (score 0):

Возможен  еще один вариант:

```
nav {
position:relative;
}

ul.dropdown {
position:absolute;
top:0;
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо! Это тот же вариант, что и у Pearson. Всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще и text-align применить, но если хочется не одно меню, то надо ещё и дополнительный блок приименять (это с любым способом):

```js
$(function() {

  $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menu = $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle();
    $('.dropdown').not(menu).hide();
  });
});
```

```css
/* Setting things up */

body {
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Important stuff */

menu {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 0.1em;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
nav {
  margin-left: 2em;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: #777;
  border-radius: .2em .2em 0 0;
}
ul.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: .5em;
  background: #777;
  min-width: 12em;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 .2em .2em;
}
ul.dropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <menu>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
  <menu>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu22</a>
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Search</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </menu>
</nav>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но тут загвоздка в коде jquery - нужно, чтобы список скрывался не только по клику по тому элементу, который список раскрыл, но и в любом месте документа. А так вариант тоже рабочий!